# FailedToTransactAsset when sending USDt from Statemint to another parachain

Tags: xcm, statemint

Now that USDt is released on Statemint, we want to use this in our parachain 'Astar'. It was no problem to send USDt from Tether to Statemint but not possible to sent the asset to another parachain.

Call data used:

```
0x1f0801010100591f01000101008419a4ac409fa4e7bec032c696c526fac10ff9114d928df56ca0bf9e9ae291490104000002043205011f0082841e000000000000
```

Error displayed on PolkadotJS:

```
error: 1000000000: 
FailedToTransactAsset
```

We are aware that USDt on Statemint is not set as isSufficients so we have DOT in our wallet to be used as transaction fee. What the difference of `approvals` (see image)?

[image: Statemint vs Statemine]

Answer (score 5):

Problem solved!
Because the asset is not set as `isSufficient` the sovereign account of the parachain needs to hold DOT on Statemint to transfer the asset through XCM.