# Does holding only sufficient asset in statemint imply there is no ED for the account?

Tags: statemint, statemine, sufficient

Do I need to account for ED when transferring Sufficient asset from statemine to parachain?

Answer (score 3):

**Does holding only sufficient asset in statemint imply there is no ED for the account?**
Yes, Sufficiency means that the asset balance is enough to create the account on-chain, with no need for the DOT/KSM existential deposit.

But, you cannot send a non-sufficient asset to an account that does not exist.
For that you need the existential deposit of the account in the native token:

The native token of Statemint is DOT. The Existential Deposit (ED), transfer fees, and the deposits for proxy/multisig operations on Statemint are about 1/10th of the values on the Relay chain. For example, the Existential Deposit of a Statemint account is 0.100 DOT, when compared to 1 DOT on Polkadot.

See the [code](https://github.com/paritytech/statemint/blob/master/runtime/statemine/src/constants.rs#L20) where the ED is set.

Statemine is the Parachain on Kusama, see the code [here](https://github.com/paritytech/statemint/blob/master/runtime/statemint/src/constants.rs#L20).

**Do I need to account for ED when transferring Sufficient asset from statemine to parachain?**
Sufficient assets can be used to pay transaction fees (i.e. there is no need to hold DOT/KSM on the account).

Bonus:
*I recommend you to take a look into [this previous answer on StackExchange](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/5923/2762) where it shares an amazing list of interesting resources on this topic.*

Comment: Is that "yes" for a topic question or post question? From the description of sufficient and non-sufficient assets [here](https://support.polkadot.network/support/solutions/articles/65000181800-what-is-statemint-and-statemine-and-how-do-i-use-them-) i assume there is no ED when I hold only USDT and transfer it somewhere, is that correct?

Comment: Sorry for a incomplete answer! I have edited my answer to clarify the two points

Comment: Actually, polkadot.js UI shows 0.7 USDT and if balance after transfer is less than that the XCM transaction fails silently, so I guess there is one. Just figured it out empirically.

Comment: What is the error? https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4982/failedtotransactasset-when-sending-usdt-from-statemint-to-another-parachain